# Watch Dogs crashes to desktop after playing for a while

Tags: technical-issues, watch-dogs

After I have been playing Watch Dogs for a while it crashes and just says "Watch Dogs stopped working... [Close program]".

Disabling UPlay in-game layout and starting UPlay in offline mode didn't help at all, but when I closed Bandicam I noticed that I can play longer until crash.

My system meets the recommended requirements, and my system doesn't overheat

```
8-core 3,5GHz (AMD FX-8320)
16GB 1600MHz RAM
7168GB of disk space
EVGA GTX770 SuperClocked ACX
```

Did you guys find out any tricks to fix Watch Dogs crashing?

Comment: I realize I have doctored on your question quite a bit, so feel free to rollback the changes. Also, legal game is a given, since we don't help with illegal games on Arqade.

Comment: @MrLemon Thanks for "doctoring" my question. I just wanted to say that the game is legal one since I have seen people asking for help for illegal copies. Let's hope downgrading nVidia driver will help.

Comment: I think I got it solved!

I installed nVidia driver version 335.23 and I closed D3DOverrider (makes FPS better in most games), Bandicam (draws FPS over game) and EVGA Precision (draws timestamp etc over game)

Comment: You should make that into an answer if it solved your problem. Please include the driver that did not work for you as well.

Comment: @MrLemon Doesn't hurt to clarify that you are using a legal copy of the game as a new user. With new user questions I first assume it's an issue with illegal copies, and I'm usually right ;)

Comment: @MrLemon I tried to send that as answer but I didn't have enough reputation to answed within 8 hours of question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: There was corrupted files. I just did verify and repair files and now it is working. It crashes sometimes (about 30-60min after start) because I run out of VRAM. How can I find which programs uses most VRAM (since Watch_Dogs uses almost 2GB with Medium textures)

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with the game until I installed the new 377.88 drivers ( I believe it's release drivers not beta ).

I've got a GTX 770 also so that may be your solution.

Here's the link to the latest drivers. (Win 7 - 8 64bit)
http://in.download.nvidia.com/Windows/337.88/337.88-desktop-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-international-whql.exe

Also when you include your specs, include your OS. 64 vs 32 is kind of a big deal.